# sync field that declared only in migrations with models.py file

Tags: django, migration

I have model field that declared only in migration file, I need to declare it in models.py file, but when I'm trying to do that I'm getting this error:

`ValueError: Error adding translation field. Model 'MyModel' already contains a field named 'name_en'.`

update: field name_en field is modeltranslation field, is it possible to declare it in models.py?

Answer (score 0):

Try by deleting the migration file and adding the field in **models.py**
Then run your `python manage.py makemigrations`

*Sometimes you need to delete your migrations files and also the database to avoid getting any errors*

Comment: idk about deleting migration file is good practice

update: field name_en field is modeltranslation field, is it possible to declare it in models.py?